# Importing in Solr

Tags: oracle, solr5

I'm trying to import some data with the /dataimport option of Solr but I have some tables that refuses to import.

I have this in the dataConfig:

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource name = "jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521/xx" user="xx" password="xx"/>
        <document>
                <entity name="NAME" query=" select STREET from TABLE_STREET">
                     <field column = "STREET" name = "STREET"/>
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And this is the only thing in schema I touch:

```
...
<field name="STREET" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  />        
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="_text"/>

<uniqueKey>STREET</uniqueKey>
...
```

I have 8 tables and I can import 6 of them, but the other 2 fail and I don't know why.

```
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-07-07 07:33:16</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2015-07-07 07:33:17</str>
<str name="Time taken">0:0:0.149</str>
</lst>
```

Seems like there isn't data on the table when I do the full-import but if I do the same select on the db it has results.

This is one of the two tables which doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE "db"."NUMBER" 
   (    "CREATE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_USER" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_PROGRAM" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OPTIMIST_LOCK" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ID_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ID_STREET" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ADD_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "PORTAL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "VIEWABLE" NUMBER(15,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_NUMBER" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_NUMBER"));
```

But this one works for example:

```
CREATE TABLE "db"."TABLE_STREET" 
   (    "CREATE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_USER" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATE_PROGRAM" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OPTIMIST_LOCK" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ID_STREET" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREET_TYPE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "ID_GEO_ENTITY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREET_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PHONETIC_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ZIP_CODE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "SEARCH_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COD" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOW_DATE" DATE, 
    "POSTAL_STREET_SECTION" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "ACTIVE_GN_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "VIEWABLE" NUMBER(15,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREET_GEO_ENTITY" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "POSTAL_ADDRESS_STREET_SECTION" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N', 
    "POSTAL_CODE_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_TABLE_STREET" PRIMARY KEY ("STREET"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a problem of the Oracle Driver, I had to use an h2 driver too.